# Animating Labels with delay and duration Ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, animation, app-store

So i was trying to animate label which will start with a text then after certain time it will fade and new text comes to the screen which will fade after certain time and then new text comes. I want this to happen recursively. I need to continue animating for 15 seconds , the again same thing happens for next 15 seconds.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self MyLabelAnimation];

}

- (void)MyLabelAnimation {
    self.myLabel.text = @"Text 1";
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        self.myLabel.alpha = 1.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:2.7 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            self.myLabel.alpha = 0.0;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            self.myLabel.text = @"Text 2";
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                self.myLabel.alpha = 1.0;
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:2.7 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
                    self.myLabel.alpha = 0.0;
                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                    self.myLabel.text = @"Text 3";
                    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                        self.myLabel.alpha = 1.0;
                    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:2.7 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
                            self.myLabel.alpha = 0.0;
                        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                            self.myLabel.text = @"Text 4";
                            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                                self.myLabel.alpha = 1.0;
                            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.0 delay:4.8 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
                                    self.myLabel.alpha = 0.0;
                                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                                    [self MyLabelAnimation];
                                }];
                            }];
                        }];
                    }];
                }];
            }];
        }];
    }];
}
```

So Here i am calling mylabel animation from viewdidload and then i called the method at the end of the completion block of 4th animation.

Here everything is working as expected but the last animation to first animation transition is **not smooth** as other transition. Is it because i missed something . I really am not able to figure out why is it happening.

Secondly, Is is the right way to get the animation like this. Or is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: I have same issue.

Comment: Does any of you know how can i pause animation while in background and again resume while in foreground

Comment: I got the answer here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39838652/4895549)

Answer (score 3):

You might find something like this a bit easier to manage:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.counter = 0;
    self.animations = @[
                        @{@"Text":@"Hello", @"Duration":@(2.7)},
                        @{@"Text":@"Text 1", @"Duration":@(2.7)},
                        @{@"Text":@"Text 2", @"Duration":@(2.7)},
                        @{@"Text":@"Text 3", @"Duration":@(2.7)},
                        @{@"Text":@"Text 4", @"Duration":@(4.8)},
                        ];

    [self animate:0];
}


- (void)animate:(int)counter {
    self.counter = counter % self.animations.count;

    NSDictionary *item = self.animations[self.counter];

    self.myLabel.alpha = 0;
    self.myLabel.text = item[@"Text"];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                     animations:^{
                         self.myLabel.alpha = 1.0;
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                                               delay:[item[@"Duration"] floatValue]
                                             options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                                          animations:^{
                                              self.myLabel.alpha = 0.0;
                                          } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                              [self animate:++self.counter];
                                          }];
                     }];
}
```

Comment: do you know how can i pause animation when app goes background ?

Comment: Add a global `BOOL` to the class called `shouldStopAnimation`. Check the value at the start of the `animate` function. If it's set, then return immediately. Add an observer for the ApplicationWillEnterBackground notification and set the bool value to `YES` when received. You can also restart the animation when coming to the foreground by setting it no `NO` and re-calling `animate:self.counter`.

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as correct if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code....

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

     [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(MyLabelAnimation:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}
- (void)MyLabelAnimation:(NSTimer*) timer {
    self->mylabel.text = @"Hello";
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        self->mylabel.alpha = 1.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:2.7 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            self->mylabel.alpha = 0.0;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            self->mylabel.text = @"Text 2";
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                self->mylabel.alpha = 1.0;
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:2.7 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
                    self->mylabel.alpha = 0.0;
                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                    self->mylabel.text = @"Text 3";
                    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                        self->mylabel.alpha = 1.0;
                    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:2.7 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
                            self->mylabel.alpha = 0.0;
                        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                            self->mylabel.text = @"Text 4";
                            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                                self->mylabel.alpha = 1.0;
                            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.0 delay:4.8 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
                                    self->mylabel.alpha = 0.0;
                                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                                     [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0 target:self selector:@selector(MyLabelAnimation:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
                                }];
                            }];
                        }];
                    }];
                }];
            }];
        }];
    }];

}
```