# Restart animation when comes back in foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

So i was trying my hands on animation. I have a UIlabel which i want to fade in on and fade out after certain period.
I successfully done it as shown in the first answer with the help of timer.

[Animation done as shown in Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39825695/animating-labels-with-delay-and-duration-ios)

Now i want to restart this animation when my app comes foreground.
Problems :-
What should i do to restart animations?

I want that when app comes in foreground, UIlabel should act as if this is the first time i am starting animation. Basically remove all animation on UIlabel and do start animation fresh.

Comment: i have already give you answer in your first question check it

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya When coming in foreground i am handling it with notifications. so i tried to again start it with [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0 target:self selector:@selector(dooratepLabelAnimation:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO]; but uilabel starts flickering.

Comment: i will give you full code work with Notification ..

Comment: when u run app first time , Animation is normal or flickering ?

Comment: at first animation is perfect, then i tap home button, then i tap on app icon, app comes back to foreground , flickering starts in uilabel

Comment: You just have to call timer method in viewwill appear. It seems that Everytime this method calls and your method calls. Use viewWillappear for that

Comment: @Jecky can you also tell me why because it seems when home button is pressed viewillappear is not getting called. Then say i present a viewcontroller then while dismissing that , viewillappear of myviewcontroller is called amd flickering starts again

Comment: @SudhanshuGupta Check my answer below. I have tested this in my demo application. If work then vote , if it is not worked then Surely downvote it

Answer (score 2):

use like add the following method in your `ViewDidLoad`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMethod) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];

-(void)myMethod
{
 // start the beiging code here
 //[self MyLabelAnimation];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0 target:self selector:@selector(MyLabelAnimation:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

Comment: I changed the code to the answer 1 in link. So i am using timer. Can you look at it too.

Comment: I did the same thing in my code but the uilabel is flickering when coming back to foreground, that is my worry. I think may be i need to remove animation first or i dont know this thing is making me crazy

Comment: @SudhanshuGupta - 100 % correct , remove animation first if it is run,

Comment: still label is flickering, i am removing animations with [self.mylabel.layer removeallanimations;]

Comment: @SudhanshuGupta - invalidate the timer also my bro

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124854/discussion-between-sudhanshu-gupta-and-anbu-karthik).

Answer (score 1):

You should do like this

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSTimer *timer;
}
@end
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated

{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(MyLabelAnimation:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
- (void)MyLabelAnimation:(NSTimer*) timer1 {
    self->_mylabel.text = @"Hello";
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        self->_mylabel.alpha = 1.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:2.7 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            self->_mylabel.alpha = 0.0;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            self->_mylabel.text = @"Text 2";
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                self->_mylabel.alpha = 1.0;
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:2.7 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
                    self->_mylabel.alpha = 0.0;
                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                    self->_mylabel.text = @"Text 3";
                    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                        self->_mylabel.alpha = 1.0;
                    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:2.7 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
                            self->_mylabel.alpha = 0.0;
                        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                            self->_mylabel.text = @"Text 4";
                            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                                self->_mylabel.alpha = 1.0;
                            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.0 delay:4.8 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
                                    self->_mylabel.alpha = 0.0;
                                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                    [self viewWillAppear:YES];
                                }];
                            }];
                        }];
                    }];
                }];
            }];
        }];
    }];

}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [timer invalidate];
}
```

Comment: thanks for doing these things .. when i press home button , sometimes the first text is shown , sometimes second. Just try to press home button and app icon to launch very fast , u will also observe the same.

Comment: @SudhanshuGupta just make one change Write viewDidAppear instead of viewWillAppear in both place. and observe it

Comment: nope its not working , when we press home and return viewwilllappear and didappear are not called

Comment: Me any my friend have tried this and working successfully but in your case I am sorry for you. Now I cant help you anymore. Thank you 

Comment: thanks for your help may be i am doing something wrong from my end

Comment: @SudhanshuGupta please give me Email Id I will send my demo build for your query and observe it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124900/discussion-between-jecky-and-sudhanshu-gupta).

Answer (score 0):

You should read [Looking to understand the iOS UIViewController lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562938/looking-to-understand-the-ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle) carefully.

The methods your are looking to use are

`viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear`

Comment: Who give this post downvote ? This answer is correct. Please I request dont give downvote to certain correct answers

Comment: No, it's not correct. These methods are not called when an app returns to the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
      [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(MyLabelAnimation:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

// **Your animation....**

```
- (void)MyLabelAnimation:(NSTimer*) timer {
    self->mylabel.text = @"Hello";
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        self->mylabel.alpha = 1.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:2.7 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            self->mylabel.alpha = 0.0;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            self->mylabel.text = @"Text 2";
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                self->mylabel.alpha = 1.0;
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:2.7 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
                    self->mylabel.alpha = 0.0;
                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                    self->mylabel.text = @"Text 3";
                    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                        self->mylabel.alpha = 1.0;
                    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:2.7 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
                            self->mylabel.alpha = 0.0;
                        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                            self->mylabel.text = @"Text 4";
                            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                                self->mylabel.alpha = 1.0;
                            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.0 delay:4.8 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
                                    self->mylabel.alpha = 0.0;
                                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                                     [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0 target:self selector:@selector(MyLabelAnimation:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
                                }];
                            }];
                        }];
                    }];
                }];
            }];
        }];
    }];

}
```

Comment: it is still flickering do i need to remove uilabel aniamtions first

Comment: one more thing , is it necessay to send a notification, can't we just use timer when coming in foreground

Comment: when u run app first time , Animation is normal or flickering ?

Comment: @SudhanshuGupta i just edit my answer now its work perfectly i check this all in my demo project u also check now.

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya I think viewillappear is not getting called when we preass home button, but lets say i have a present view controller , which i present in this viewcontroller then viewwill appear is getting called and again flickering starts

Comment: Its call Brother check it i already done this think so now its your turn just use  my code .

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya really viewwillappear is not called when we press homebutton and launch again. But flickering will start as i start timer call again

Comment: i have use this code and in my demo project is work completely .

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for the question I have asked.
Inwit done it with the help of a bool variable which sets to No when app goes in background and will get set to yes when goes in foreground.

SO the next animation depends on the bool value.

Here is the link for the answer
[Restart animation after pause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39838652/4895549)